# How to get class mapping information at runtime in Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Where does NHibernate store mapping information at runtime and how to access it? I need to get association properties (complex properties) for a given mapped class at runtime. And i can't rely on reading hbm files because, mapping can be done in fluent nhibernate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can use `ISessionFactory.GetClassMetadata` to get a metadata object for each persistant type.

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/NHibernate/NHibernate/ISessionFactory/M/GetClassMetadata

Answer (score 2):

You can get it using the `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.GetClassMapping` which I found is more detailed than the `NHibernate.ISessionFactory.GetClassMetadata`.

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/NHibernate/NHibernate/Configuration/M/GetClassMapping